# I need to get values of fij for different t values. Wrote the following matlab code but its not working. Could you please guide!

Tags: exponential-function, matlab

I have written the following code in MATLAB, trying to compute $\{f_{ij}\}_{i,j=1}^2 = -2e^{i+j-t}$ for different values of $t$.

```
for t=0.1:0.1:1
    for i=1:2
        for j=1:2
            fij(i,j)= -2*exp(i+j-t);
        end
    end
end
```

I know after running this, I am supposed to get $f_{11} = -2e^{1.9} \approx 13.37$, but instead, I am getting
$$
f_{ij} \approx \begin{bmatrix}
-5.4366  & -14.7781 \\
-14.7781 & -40.1711
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Could you please help me understand the problem?

Comment: what is not working exactly?

Comment: M not very good at programming. i know that after running this, -2*exp(1.9) must be first answer but i got                                                                                            -5.4366  -14.7781
  -14.7781  -40.1711

Comment: fix $t=0.1$ to get what you want. Your result is for $t=1$

Comment: How must the code be modified to get all the fij for all values of t, not just t=1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your code is repeatedly generating $f_{ij}(t)$ for different values of $t$ in $\{0.1,0.2,\ldots, 1\}$, and each consecutive calculation over-writes the one before, so you end up with the final value of $f_{ij}(1)$.

If you just want to get the values for one value of $t$:

```
t=0.1
for i=1:2
    for j=1:2
        fij(i,j)= -2*exp(i+j-t);
    end
end
```

If you want them all, you can use
for k=1:10
t = k*0.1
for i=1:2
for j=1:2
fij(k,i,j)= -2*exp(i+j-t);
end
end
end

Then, `f(1,:,:)` will be $f_{ij}(0.1)$ and `f(10,:,:)` will be $f_{ij}(1)$.

Comment: for k=1:10 
    t = 0.1
    
    for i=1:2 
        for j=1:2 
            fij(k,i,j)= -2exp(i+j-t); 
        end
    end
end        
Tried this, but its not working

Comment: i got it. Thank you so much _/\_